# SAS hard disk drive not showing up windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

i have [HP proliant ml350 g6](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-proliant-ml350-g6-xeon-e5520-2-26-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/) with windows server 2012 r2, and i have 4 SAS (hp SAS 300GB * 4) hard disk drive linked in plug drive bays [(see number 3 in the picture )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBBSt.gif), when i was installing windows server only one disk show up in partitions window and the other disks (3) not show up . i thought they will show later after installing the server . 
now i am trying to use them but i can't see them in Disk Management or File and storage services in Server Manager .. 
do i missed something or i should to install any new role to make them show up like RAID or something ?

Comment: It depends on what your RAID configuration is set to. What is the total capacity of the "drive" that you installed the operating system to?

Comment: the total capacity as i said  300 GB

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment I'd  start with looking at your Raid controller. If you have 300GB times 4 then it should be 1.2 TB if it's a RAID 0, Raid 1 would be 600GB, etc. So it sounds like your raid controller is only set up to pass one drive through. The other drives may not be initialized.

Comment: so how to find my RAID controller in windows server ?
i didn't install it yet

Comment: It's an option you get to before the computer boots. It will be one of the prompts you get during the boot screens.

Comment: i tried to find it in BIOS but not exist .. and i don't think that it's show up during booting

Comment: It generally isn't part of the BIOS. It will be a prompt along the lines of "Press [some key combination] to configure your RAID. Based on the product description page that you provided it must have some type of RAID controller in the system. Without knowing how that is configured, it's all guess work.

Comment: i can understand now , i google about the server hardware and this is what i got :

-STORAGE:
RAID Level RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 10, RAID 5
-Type : none

-STORAGE CONTROLLER:
Interface Type Serial ATA-150 / SAS
-Storage Controller Name: Smart Array P410i
-Buffer Size: 256 MB
-STORAGE CONTROLLER (2ND):
Type: 1 x SATA - integrated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not have set up your server with the RAID configuration correctly. The HP ProLiant ML350 G6 typically supports various RAID configurations that allow you to use multiple hard drives in a more fault-tolerant and efficient manner. If you've installed the Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system and only one disk is showing up, it's likely that the other disks are not properly configured or recognized by the operating system.

Try entering the RAID configuration utility during the server's boot-up process. This is usually accessible by pressing a specific key combination (like F8 or Ctrl + S) when prompted. In the RAID configuration utility, you can create a RAID array using your SAS drives. Depending on your requirements, you might want to set up a RAID 1 (mirroring) or RAID 5 (striping with parity) configuration for data redundancy and better performance.

Also ensure that you have installed the RAID controller drivers for your server. Check the HP website for the specific drivers required for your server model and operating system version. You can load these drivers during the Windows installation process by pressing a specific key when prompted.

Once you've configured the RAID array and loaded the necessary drivers, boot into Windows Server. Open the Disk Management utility by right-clicking on the "Computer" icon, selecting "Manage," and then navigating to "Disk Management." You should see the additional disks as unallocated space. Right-click on each unallocated disk and choose to initialize and format them. You can choose to create new partitions or extend existing ones as needed. If the disks are still not showing up, try rescanning for disks within the Disk Management utility. Sometimes, Windows might not automatically detect newly added disks.